# Find all x values such that $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(x-1)^n}{3^n}}$ converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

$\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(x-1)^n}{3^n}}$

Find all x values where it converges, how can I do it without using the root test?

Comment: By noticing that it's a geometric series

Comment: It's a geometric series; do you know what conditions on a geometric series imply convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Without any test:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(x-1)^n}{3^n}=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{x-1}3\right)^n
=\frac{\frac{x-1}3-\left(\frac{x-1}3\right)^{N+1}}{1-\frac{x-1}3}.
\end{align}
For this to converge as $N\to\infty$ we need that $\left|\frac{x-1}3\right|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{(x-1)^n}{3^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left(\frac{x-1}{3}\right)^n=-\frac{3^{-m}\left((x-1)^m-3^m\right)\left(x-1\right)}{x-4}$$

So if $m\rightarrow\infty$ it converges when $|x-1|<3$ so $-2<x<4$

Answer (score 0):

the test that goes for convergence is that mod of the given number should be less than 1 then its summation of  infinity is given by $\frac{a}{(1-r)}$ where a is first term r is common ratio so here clearly we will have to get get that $\frac{x-1}{3}$ is less than 1 and for divergent series mod of that number could be anything greater than $1$. so here values of x can be given by $+,-(x-1)$ is less than 3 which implies $x=(-2,4)$. Hope it helps you.